# Using JS to respond to list item event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I am trying to use to following code to change the HTML of a div element with ID "text"

HTML code:

```
<ul> 
      <li value="1" onclick="changeText(this.value);">about</li>
      <li value="2" onclick="changeText(this.value);">reg</li>
      <li value="3" onclick="changeText(this.value);">home</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function changeText(value){  
  var text=document.getElementById("text");     
  if(value==1)text.innerHTML("You clicked on about!");
  if(value==2)text.innerHTML("You clicked on reg!");
  if(vaule==3)text.innerHTML("You clicked on home!");      
 //alignDiv();  
}
```

However, as it is, it doesn't change the HTML of the Div element. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A `li` element should have no `value` attribute.

Comment: accourding to [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) it can...

Comment: `If the element is a child of an ol element` - and you are using an `ul`.

Comment: I see. well now I tried `<li onclick="changeText(3);">home</li>`. This doesnt work either and I'm not using value...

Comment: See my answer. I added this `value` thing as a comment because it has nothing to do with problem, but it is still important to mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Problem

If you are looking at the error message in the console, it is quite helpful:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'innerHTML' of object #`<HTMLDivElement>`
> is not a function

You should always use the console (let that be Chrome Console, Firebug, Opera Dragonfly, IE Developer Tools) while developing, it is a very valuable tool.

#### Solution

`innerHTML` is a property, not a method, so you should set it like this:

```
text.innerHTML = "You clicked on about!";
```

[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/37yx7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

1. => `.innerHTML(` is wrong. You do : `text.innerHTML = "whatever"`
2. `<li>` doesn't have a value attribute so its not all that great to just give it that attribute. (Although it works)

Using the new html5 [element.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset) and `data-` attributes would be a nice solution to this.

Your code would look like this:

```
<script>
 function changeText(item){//item is an li
    var text = document.getElementById("text");  
    //we check the dataset for the value attribute
    console.log(item.dataset.value);
    if(item.dataset.value === "1")
    { 
      text.innerHTML = "You clicked on about!";
    }
    else if(item.dataset.value === "2")
    { 
      text.innerHTML = "You clicked on reg!";
    } else if (item.dataset.value === "3")
    { 
      text.innerHTML = "You clicked on home!";
    }
}
</script>
<div id="text" > Content here </div>
<ul> <!--we send the li element into the changeText function -->
      <li data-value="1" onclick="changeText(this);">about</li>
      <li data-value="2" onclick="changeText(this);">reg</li>
      <li data-value="3" onclick="changeText(this);">home</li>
</ul>​
```

See a live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/BJBaP/1/